# Look Up Field in Access

Tags: ms-access, lookup

I have two tables. One has information that is collected from an infopath form. The other has a list of names and employee ids. Is there a way to have a column in the first table that searches table 2 with an employee ID and looks up the name associated with that ID?

The first table has a checkin, checkout, and employee ID column.
The second table has Name and employee ID.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two tables have the `[employee ID]` column in common, you can use a query which joins them based on that column.

```sql
SELECT
    t1.[employee ID],
    t2.Name,
    t1.checkin,
    t1.checkout
FROM
    [first table] AS t1
    INNER JOIN [second table] AS t2
    ON t1.[employee  ID] = t2.[employee ID];
```